# Is it possible to generate a variant from an integer sequence?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

Would it be possible to generate a variant from an integer sequence like in this pseudo C++ sample:

```
#include <utility>
#include <variant>

template <int MyInt>
struct MyStruct{};

using MyIntegerSequence = std::make_integer_sequence<int, 3>;

using MyVariant = std::variant<MyStruct<MyIntegerSequence>...>; // Does not compile

int main()
{
    return sizeof(MyVariant);    
}
```

On coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2439048b107642c2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, sure. The key is that one must use a pack expansion of some sort. Your struct takes an `int` non-type template parameter. So we must expand the integer sequence's pack to feed them into `MyStruct` one at a time.

`MyStruct<MyIntegerSequence>...` is not a pack expansion, since there is no template definition and no pack in that context.

For example, with a class template (and partial specialization):

```
template<typename Seq> struct MyVariantHelper;

template<int... Is> struct MyVariantHelper<std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>> {
    using type = std::variant<MyStruct<Is>...>;
};

using MyVariant = MyVariantHelper<MyIntegerSequence>::type;
```

---

Or with a function template and `decltype`:

```
template<int... Is>
auto MyVariantHelper(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>) 
  -> std::variant<MyStruct<Is>...>;

using MyVariant = decltype(MyVariantHelper(MyIntegerSequence{}));
```

Comment: I had forgotten this kind of pattern matching in the template specialization (to extract the int... pack of the sequence). This is crystal clear. Thank you for your answer! :)